# Android support bottomsheet scrim color

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-coordinatorlayout, androiddesignsupport

I have successfully implemented the bottomsheets as per **support update 23.2**, but I do not get the scrim color (window dim) effect when the bottom sheet is expanded.
I see the `coordinatorlayout` contains a `getscrimcolor` method but no set.

Answer (score 5):

BottomSheetDialog is the right way to create modal bottom sheets (elevated and with dimming), while BottomSheetBehavior is the right one to create persistent bottom sheets (not elevated and without dimming).

Look at [Android Support Library 23.2](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) and at [Material Bottom sheets](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/bottom-sheets.html#) for differences between *Modal* and *Persistent*.

Answer (score 4):

```
BottomSheetDialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(getActivity());
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_bottom_sheet);
dialog.show();
```

A solution I found is to use the `BottomSheetDialog` class which already contains the dim window flags like a normal dialog.

Not sure if this is the right way but for now it works.